# Unknown USB stick included with new PS3 controller?

Tags: ps3, controllers, hardware-identification

I recently bought a third-party PS3 controller, and I also received this USB stick (below) with the package.

It has two settings on it marked "RX" and "FC" - the latter has a small button next to it. No manual was included and I could not find any hint on Google.

Does anyone know what the USB stick is for - is it for using the controller with a PC?

[image: controller] [image: USB-stick]

Comment: Is this an official Sony controller or 3rd party? I would absolutely not plug the stick into **any** device if this was marketed as an official 1st party Sony PlayStation controller.

Comment: Sorry guys I know I came back on this a bit late which probably explains the downvote :-)

Now that I look at the controller it is definitely a 3rd part controller - never noticed it when I ordered it

Answer (score 5):

It is probably a wireless connector to this controller. The controller from photos is some kind of 3rd party hardware, so it is possible that it can't connect with PS3 like the original Dual Shock.
This stick is the receiver of the wireless signal from the controller. It will be work as good as other 3rd party wired controller, which is also working by plug the cable into the USB port in PS3.